# How to generate a series of points in a convex set?

Tags: stochastic-processes

For an arbitrary convex set, may be a polyhedron or an ellipsoid how can I generate N uniformly distributed points inside?

Comment: What do you mean by uniformly distributed?

Answer (score 1):

Generate points uniformly in a rectangle that contains the set and keep only those that are in the set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and any methodology to solve this problem to arbitrary convex set, such as a convex hull of a set of points.